# Count similar string values in pandas dataframe per year

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

Having the dataset below. I would like to count the occurrences of a string in a certain year. In reality I have a much bigger dataframe a multiple years. How do I combine a groupby approach and count the different string values?

`df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1':['A','B','D','A'],'col2':['B','C','E','E'],'col3':['C','D','',''],'col4':['D','E','','']},index = ['01-01-2000','02-01-2000','01-01-2001','02-01-2001'])`

```
           col1 col2 col3 col4
01-01-2000    A    B    C    D
02-01-2000    B    C    D    E
01-01-2001    D    E          
02-01-2001    A    E
```

desired result:

```
           count
A    2000    1
A    2001    1
B    2000    2    
B    2001    0
C    2000    2
C    2001    0
D    2000    2
D    2001    1
E    2000    1
E    2001    2
```

Comment: Your example code does not generate the example df in your post...

Comment: The code produces a different dataframe than you are showing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create new column `year` in [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), then reshape by [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), remove empty strings by [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html), get counts by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html), add missing categories by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and last use [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

df = (df.assign(year = df.index.year)
        .melt('year', value_name='val')
        .query("val != ''")
        .groupby(['val','year'])
        .size()
        .unstack(fill_value=0)
        .stack()
        .reset_index(name='count')
        )
print (df)
  val  year  count
0   A  2000      2
1   A  2001      1
2   B  2000      2
3   B  2001      0
4   C  2000      2
5   C  2001      0
6   D  2000      1
7   D  2001      1
8   E  2000      1
9   E  2001      2
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let's replace your empty cells with empty values (for example, `np.nan`), and let's set your index to be a [datetime index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1':['A','B','D','A'],'col2':['B','C','E','E'],'col3':['C','D','',''],'col4':['D','E','','']},index = ['01-01-2000','02-01-2000','01-01-2001','02-01-2001'])
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index)
df.replace('',np.nan, inplace=True)
```

(I've also changed the code to fit the example in your question)

To get your result:

```
result = df.apply(lambda row: row.value_counts(), axis=1).resample('1Y').sum().stack().reorder_levels([1, 0]).sort_index()
```

Which yields:

```
A  2000-12-31    1.0
   2001-12-31    1.0
B  2000-12-31    2.0
   2001-12-31    0.0
C  2000-12-31    2.0
   2001-12-31    0.0
D  2000-12-31    2.0
   2001-12-31    1.0
E  2000-12-31    1.0
   2001-12-31    2.0
```

Let's break it down:

- `df.apply(lambda row: row.value_counts(), axis=1)` transforms your dataframe to have 'A' to 'E' in columns, and the number of occurrences in cell:

  ```
              A   B   C   D   E
  2000-01-01  1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 NaN
  2000-02-01  NaN 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
  2001-01-01  NaN NaN NaN 1.0 1.0
  2001-02-01  1.0 NaN NaN NaN 1.0
  ```
- `.resample('1Y').sum()` is using [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html), which is just a fancy [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) that deals well with a datetime index, to sum occurrences by year. It yields:

  ```
              A   B   C   D   E
  2000-12-31  1.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 1.0
  2001-12-31  1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 2.0
  ```
- [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), [reorder_levels](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reorder_levels.html) and sort_index just bring the results to the desired format (well, almost... note that instead of a year it shows the last day of that year)